# PostgresSql connectin not establish on first request through c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, connection, npgsql

I am trying to connect postgresSQL from c#, but facing issue that on first connection, it times out, and same on second time it gives me proper data. Again after idling of some time, I am trying same thing again, and same thing happens as above.

PostgresSQL Version : postgresql-11

Comment: It’s old problem read about pgbouncer.

Comment: What timeout is timing out?  What is it set to?  Sounds like maybe DNS problem.  Once the address is cached, it works.  But cache misses are slow to resolve.

Comment: It times out within a first second but timeout is set to 15 second

Comment: Can you please post the full exception and stack trace? Also, do you see the same thing happening from outside C#? For example, try using the psql command line tool on the same machine to connect to the same database. Other than that, it does sound like it may be related to a DNS problem, where the your server is taking too long to answer, but then caches the result for a while.